# What are the practical implications of the eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix being purely imaginary or zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

I analyse real-world data by decomposing asymmetric square matrices with zero diagonals into a symmetric and a skew-symmetric part, and treating the eigenstructure of the skew-symmetric part as providing canonical variates, in a method proposed by Gower.  I find this provides often strikingly interpretable results and am working towards encapsulating it with additional analyses in a piece of software.  For instance, simple rotation of the axes often produces instantly interpretable patterns.  The first two eigenvalues typically, but not always, account for 98% of the variance in the matrix.

Does the fact that the eigenvalues are purely imaginary have any practical consequences that may not be apparent to a non-mathematician long used to working with real positive definite matrices?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the method proposed by Gower that you're referring to, so it's hard to know what properties of skew-symmetric matrices might be relevant here. Could you explain the method in further detail, or perhaps provide a link to a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Constantine, A G and Gower, J C (1978) Graphical representation of asymmetric matrices. Appl. Stat., 27, 297-304. Plotting the eigenvectors associated with the largest pair of eigenvalues crams a lot of information into a simple graph, though the interpretation is not intuitive., because it is based on the areas of triangles where one vertex is always the origin of the graph.  I am finding some very interesting results, and am considering rotations of the axes of plots of the first two pairs.  I want to be sure what I do is mathematically pukkah.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation
$$
\dot x(t) + Ax(t)=0
$$
is norm-conserving (energy-conserving) for skew-symmetric $A$ in the sense that
$$
\|x(t)\|_2= \|x(0)\|_2
$$
for all $t$. This might be compared to $|\exp(it)|=1$ for all $t$.

If $A$ would be positive definite the $\|x(t)\|_2$ would decay exponentially fast.